# How to fix UnexpectedValueException thrown with message "Invalid route action: ... In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I can't do anything cause appears the message UnexpectedValueException thrown with message "Invalid route action:

> [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController].

And now I can't even run mi server. When I do 'php artisan serve' also appear that error
How can I fix it?

Comment: okay, is there a question here, or you are just making statements?

Comment: In RouteAction.php line 87 is the problem

Comment: Jaajaj, I wana solve it

Comment: can post your route?

Comment: Where can I find my route?

Comment: what's the last thing you did before it happens?

Comment: can you run 'php artisan' without error? if not maybe theres a semicolon missing on route file.

Answer (score 0):

In latest laravel versions there is a folder routes in route directory. routes/web.php
in the web.php you can find your routes.
In older versions you have to search in app/http folder file name routes.php.

By the error it seems your route is not able to reaching your controller.
Resons:
1. Different Namespace.
2. incorrect spelling| check case sensitive error.